Windows stretched and cut off, cannot resize
I accidentally pressed some buttons while Terminal was open and I was carrying my MacBook, and now all my applications seem to insist to use the top half of the screen, and also to cut off all four edges.  Example: 
Notice how the status bar at the bottom is cut off, as is the option menu at the top.  It's hard to tell this from the picture, but about 2 inches' worth of PDF file is cut off on the left.
I tried dragging the size to see if I can get another window open in the background, but as I try to resize, the window size does not change, but the amount of information displayed does decrease; the displayed information simply stretches:

At this point the amount of PDF file displayed is so small that you start seeing the status bar and the option menu of the PDF file; notice how stretched the text there appears.
If I keep trying to make the window smaller, eventually little is left other than the title bar, which again gets stretched to fill the same size on the display:

If I double-click the title bar, the window does get maximized correctly (but again, I cannot get another window on the screen).  In this case, in displays the left side but cuts off the right side; however, I am able to zoom out so that the whole document's width is on the screen (and a gap on the left).
Interestingly, if I click Full Screen view from the menu bar instead of double-clicking the title bar, it results in the same half-window size, but simply with black background.  Clicking Tile or Cascade windows still arranges them in the way described here.
This happens with all the windows, not just a single application. Also, some grey strip is now present on all four sides of the screen. Does anyone have a clue what's going on here?  Can I move the windows using Terminal?

Go to Settings > Displays and change the screen resolution. This should force a rearrangement of the windows. Do you connect this Mac to an external monitor?

I've tried this, happens under all resolutions.  No external monitor ever used with this Mac.

Do you have access to an external monitor? Perhaps connecting one will help. That smearing of the screen in the last image is worrisome. You should run Apple Diagnostics to see if there are any HW problems. Also - try booting into Safe Mode to see if the problem appears. Lastly, try resetting NVRAM which stores screen resolution settings.

I presume you've quit all the apps and restarted the Mac?

Another thing to try is if you can open/view your terminal window, you can use the history command or just press the Up arrow key to see which commands you've entered that may have triggered it. I suspect it was a defaults write command that changed a plist file or something. So, you could reverse it by just using defaults delete on the particular line causing your display arrangement issue
